# Get my address with InetAddress in Android

Tags: java, android, inetaddress

I have this JAVA code

```
package com.log.app;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Adressage {

    public static String GetMyAdress() {

        InetAddress address;
        String HostIP = null;

        try {

            address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            HostIP = address.getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return HostIP;
    }
}
```

And i have a table in my Activity.java in which i am going to call the method in that class to show the IP address of my device

```
    tr.addView(generateTextView(Adressage.GetMyAdress(), layoutParams));
```

When i launch my emulator and go to the view of this activity the app stops and i have this error

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.log.app/com.log.app.SurActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

I am newbie with ANDROID and it looks like android blocks any networking code in its main thread so what is the solution for this ?

Comment: The message error says you should call InetAddress methods on a different thread

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your onCreate method:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

And don't forget your internet permission in your AndroidManifest file!

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```